# Automatic link to database style in QGIS vanished

Tags: qgis, postgresql, style, database

I have a couple of shapes in a PostgreSQL database link with QGIS. Once, I created specific styles for these layers and saved them in the PostgreSQL database as default style. Now, I loaded the project and all styles are vanished, i.e. the link to the presetted styles in the databse are gone. When I try to load the style again from database the correct style is shown as related style and option. But after closing the QGIS project the style is vanished again. Why is that?

Comment: If the saved style is present in the postgres database, then the issue is probably related to the QGIS project files. Have you tried creating a new project, loading the layers from postgres, applying style, saving the project, then closing and reopening it again? What's the result?

Comment: Then it is fine. So I am afraid I'll have to build a new project from scratch.